# Getting all the combinations in an array

Tags: c#

Say I have the following array:

```
var arr = new[] { "A", "B", "C" };
```

How can I produce all the possible combinations that contain only two characters and no two the same (e.g. `AB` would be the same as `BA`).  For example, using the above array it would produce:

```
AB
AC
BC
```

Please note that this example has been simplified. The array and the length of the string required will be greater.

I'd really appreciate if someone could help.

Comment: do you need AB, AC, BC, and ABC ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These should give you a starting point:
http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2004/09/16/permuterate
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/Combinatorics.aspx

Answer (score 9):

Lets extend it, so maybe we can see the pattern:

```
string[] arr = new string[] { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E" };

//arr[0] + arr[1] = AB
//arr[0] + arr[2] = AC
//arr[0] + arr[3] = AD
//arr[0] + arr[4] = AE

//arr[1] + arr[2] = BC
//arr[1] + arr[3] = BD
//arr[1] + arr[4] = BE

//arr[2] + arr[3] = CD
//arr[2] + arr[4] = CE

//arr[3] + arr[4] = DE
```

I see two loops here.

- The first (outer) loop goes from 0 to 4 (arr.Length - 1)
- The second (inner) loop goes from the outer loops counter + 1 to 4 (arr.Length)

Now it should be easy to translate that to code!

Answer (score 5):

This code

```
var strs = new[] {"A", "B", "C", "D"};
var combinations = CreateCombinations(0, "", strs);
var text = string.Join(", ", combinations);

private List<string> CreateCombinations(int startIndex, string pair, string[] initialArray)
    {
        var combinations = new List<string>();
        for (int i = startIndex; i < initialArray.Length; i++)
        {
            var value = $"{pair}{initialArray[i]}";
            combinations.Add(value);
            combinations.AddRange(CreateCombinations(i + 1, value, initialArray));
        }

        return combinations;
    }
```

The text variable will contain

```
A, AB, ABC, ABCD, ABD, AC, ACD, AD, B, BC, BCD, BD, C, CD, D
```

Answer (score 1):

Since ordering does not matter, these are actually combinations and not permutations.  In any case, there is some sample code [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/Combinatorics.aspx) (you want the section entitled "Combinations (i.e., without Repetition)".

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking for are combinations, not permutations (the latter term implies that order matters). Anyway, it's a classic use for recursion. In pseudo-code:

```
def combs(thearray, arraylen, currentindex, comblen):
  # none if there aren't at least comblen items left,
  # or comblen has gone <= 0
  if comblen > arraylen - currentindex or comblen <= 0:
    return
  # just 1 if there exactly comblen items left
  if comblen == arraylen - currentindex:
    yield thearray[currentindex:]
    return
  # else, all combs with the current item...:
  for acomb in combs(thearray, arraylen, currentindex+1, comblen-1):
    yield thearray[currentindex] + acomb
  # ...plus all combs without it:
  for acomb in combs(thearray, arraylen, currentindex+1, comblen):
    yield acomb
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public string[] Permute(char[] characters)
{
    List<string> strings = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < characters.Length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < characters.Length; j++)
        {
            strings.Add(new String(new char[] { characters[i], characters[j] }));
        }
    }

    return strings.ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the sum of 1 to n-1 or n(n-1) / 2.

```
int num = n * ( n - 1 ) / 2;
```

Obviously you could generalize the n * ( n - 1 ) using a pair of factorials for whatever you are trying to do (string size wise).

Answer (score 0):

Wrote an answer for a question that turned out to be marked as duplicate, pointing here.

```
var arr = new[] { "A", "B", "C" };

var arr2 = arr1.SelectMany(
    x => arr1.Select(
        y => x + y));
```

Produced the correct output when enumerated into console in VS2013. `SelectMany` will flatten the internal `IEnumerable` generated from the inner `Select`.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
    public static void Mutate (char[] Nums, int Idx = 0)
    {
        if (Idx == Nums.Length)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(' ', Nums));
            return;
        }
        for (var i = Idx; i < Nums.Length; i++)
        {
            (Nums[Idx], Nums[i]) = (Nums[i], Nums[Idx]);
            Mutate(Nums, Idx + 1);
            (Nums[Idx], Nums[i]) = (Nums[i], Nums[Idx]);
        }
    }
```

Test With:

```
Mutate(new char[] { '1', '2', '3' });
```

Output:

> 1 2 3
> 1 3 2
> 2 1 3
> 2 3 1
> 3 2 1
> 3 1 2

Answer (score -1):

What you are looking for is an double Loop along the lines of the following pseudo code.

```
for(int i = FirstElement; i<= LastElement; increment i) {
    for(j = i; j<= lastElement; increment j) {
        if(i != j) {
            print (i, j)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's an oversimplification of combinatorics. How would your code  work when the number of combinations becomes larger, say, 10-letter combinations from a 26-letter array (26 choose 10, no repeats)?