# Different combinations of an array (C#)

Tags: c#, algorithm, combinations

how can we find out different combination of the elements of an array using c# code.
are there any inbuilt library function for this.?

for eg: suppose an array has elements {2,3,4,5,6,7}
then the possible combination would be 2,3,4,5,6,7,2 3,2 3 4,2 3 4 5,  etc

so basically wat i need is a function which gives different combination based on its input for eg: comb(array,2) gives output 2 3,1 2,3 4 and comb(array,3) gives output 1 2 3,2 3 4,3 4 5 and so on

Eg: valid comnbination for array= {1, 2, 3} and length = 2 are 1 2,1 3,2 3 .....

Comment: What combinations do you want?

Comment: What do you mean by "combination"? Do you mean all "combinations"where elements in a different order are considered the same and all elements of the array are "combined" as their own arrays?

Comment: What do you actually mean with "different combination"?

Comment: Are you looking for permutations? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272828/getting-all-the-permutations-in-an-array

Comment: (Downvoted for lack of clarity, by the way. If you clarify the question, I'll happily remove the downvote. At the moment, the question can't really be answered with any confidence that the answer will satisfy what you're actually trying to do.)

Comment: i have updated my Question plz check

Comment: Your example doesn't make any sense for me. Can you explain how did you get that 'combination'?

Comment: so basically wat i need is a function which gives different combination based on its input for eg: comb(array,2) gives output 2 3,1 2,3 4 and comb(array,3) gives output 1 2 3,2 3 4,3 4 5 and so on

Comment: so basically wat i need is a function which gives different combination based on its input for eg: comb(array,2) gives output 2 3,1 2,3 4 and comb(array,3) gives output 1 2 3,2 3 4,3 4 5 and so on

Comment: updated my question...plz be humble enough 2 check it once again....

Comment: @Jay: Okay, so you want all possible permutations *of a given length*. (The question could still be clearer, to be honest...) Um, hang on - the examples you've given have all kept the element order - is that a requirement too? Or is "3 1 2" a valid combination?

Comment: no element order is not required......ya 3 1 2 is a valid combination..

Comment: if 3 1 2 is a valid one, then I'm lost :)

Comment: Jay, no offence, usually when someone is working on an algorithm he/she needs first to be able to produce "on paper" a solution for a given input. If the words are not enough to describe the problem, an example  of input/output should be enough. So please update your question, for the following input: array= {1, 2, 3} and length = 2 what are all the possible outputs you're expecting

Comment: Here r the valid combinations 1 2,1 3,2 3 ....and i'm sorry for the above 3 1 2 combination..its nt valid...i was confused...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
static void Main()
{
    var cnk = comb(new [] {1,2,3},2);
    foreach ( var c in cnk)
    {
    }
}

public static IEnumerable<int[]> comb(int[] a, int k)
{
    if (a == null || a.Length == 0 || k < 1 || k > a.Length)
        yield break;

    int n = a.Length;   
    // 1
    if ( k == 1)
        for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {   
            yield return new int[] {a[i]};
        }
    else
        {
            // k
            for ( int i = 0; i < n - k + 1; i++)
            {
                var res = new int[k];
                    for (int t = i, c = 0; t < i + k - 1; t++, c++)                 
                        res[c] = a[t];              
                for (int j = i + k - 1; j < n; j++)
                {                                                               
                    res[k-1] = a[j];                    
                    yield return res;
                }
            }
        }
}
```

You should take the algorithm from here, <s>my answer doesn't solve your problem</s>
[Algorithm to return all combinations of k elements from n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127704/algorithm-to-return-all-combinations-of-k-elements-from-n)

Answer (score 0):

Seemed logic is not absolutely correct as:

```
var cnk = comb(new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 }, 3);
```

This gives 3 variants, but as a matter of fact it is 4:

```
1 2 3
1 2 4
1 3 4
2 3 4
```

I guess comb is better to be implemented in recursive way.