# Combination of two elements in array

Tags: c#, arrays

I had similar questions in the past - I have array with n elements in it, how can I get all combinations of two elements from it, without repeating?

Ie. if array is like this:

```
var arr1 = new[] { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E"};
```

... result should be

```
AB
AC
AD
AE
BC
BD
BE
CD
CE
CD
```

Can you help me please achieve this?

Comment: the last should be `DE` not `CD`

Comment: Why did you write `CD` twice? And where is `DE` ?

Comment: dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272828/getting-all-the-combinations-in-an-array

Comment: Can be considered BC as CB?

Comment: Possible answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4319049/generating-permutations-using-linq

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following Code...

```
var arr1 = new[] { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E" };
var combinations = new List<string>();
for(int i = 0; i < arr1.Length; i++)
{
    for (int j = i + 1; j < arr1.Length; j++)
    {
        combinations.Add(string.Format("{0}{1}", arr1[i], arr1[j]));
    }
}
```

Good Luck!

Added screenshot for reference...

[image]

Comment: This one's also goof although I think the answer from @jim tollan looks nicer because he doesn't need an extra if statement. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var arr1 = new[] { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E" };
var combinations = new List<string>();
foreach (var i in arr1) {
    foreach (var j in arr1) {
         if((int)i.ToCharArray()[0] < (int)j.ToCharArray()[0]) {
             combinations.Add(i + j);
         }
    }
}
```

now the combinations list contains all combinations!

Comment: I upvoted it but later understood that it is incorrect. It will produce both AB and BA which is not wanted.

Comment: @sjkm: But it's still the wrong result (20 instead of 10).

Comment: You allow `AB` to be in the result as well as `BA`, while only `AB` is expected!

Comment: Ah I see, but now it should be right

Answer (score 1):

ok, my feeble attempt:

```
var myArray = new[] { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E" };
var myCombos = new List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < myArray.Length; i++)
{
    for (int j = (i + 1); j < myArray.Length; j++)
    {
        myCombos.Add(myArray[i] + myArray[j]);
    }
}
```

now we have:

AB
AC
AD
AE
BC
BD
BE
CD
CE
DE

Comment: Seems the only correct attempt so far.. :)

Comment: yeah, and i certainly aint no genius - lol. had to think back to the old basic posers from way back. nice brain teaser tho

Comment: No, you haven't got downvotes. I can see up/down votes apart per answer and it only says 1up/0down => +1.

Comment: paranoid -who's paranoid :-)?!?. must be my friday madness going on. btw, enjoyed your curating of the answers, makes it feel quite *live*. nice one - have a grt weekend Abbas

Answer (score 0):

Try following (cross join in LINQ)

```
  var arr1 = new[] { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E"};
  var result = (from i1 in arr1
             from i2 in arr1.Where( i=> i[0]>i1[0])
            select i1+i2).ToArray();
```

Snippet result on ideone [here](http://ideone.com/ifgFUG)

```
AB
AC
AD
AE
BC
BD
BE
CD
CE
DE
```

Comment: You should filter same el pairs, like "AA"

Comment: too fast and too inexact :)

Comment: And filter out BA etc.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this little LINQ query:

```
var allCombinations = from str1 in arr1
                      from str2 in arr1
                      where str1.CompareTo(str2) < 0
                      select str1 + str2;
Console.Write(string.Join(",", allCombinations));
```

My last is different, i assume that was a typo in your result: `AB,AC,AD,AE,BC,BD,BE,CD,CE,DE`

Comment: Why don't you run it first? It clearly produces different result than the one asked in the question.