# C# code to get combination of words in an array

Tags: c#, arrays, combinations, cpu-word

Input is string[] Arr=new string []{"aa","bb","cc"};

Output should be:

aa,
bb,
cc,
aabb,
aacc,
bbaa,
bbcc,
ccaa,
ccbb,
aabbcc,
aaccbb,
bbaacc,
bbccaa,
ccaabb,
ccbbaa

Comment: What have you done so far? show us some code please.

Comment: Maybe start [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272828/getting-all-the-combinations-in-an-array), or search for similar questions.

Comment: since this is your first question here. You need to show us 1) your code which you wrote trying to solve your problem. 2) a description of the problems that you have encountered. 3) preferably the output that your code has generated. The input and the expected output is already posted. So that is good. You are almost there. If you add the rest of the inforrmation we can start helping you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting all the combinations in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272828/getting-all-the-combinations-in-an-array)